# how to remove <select> drop down icon background color in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

remove **select** -- **option** tag drop down icon button **background color** in firefox.

Here is HTML Code

```
 <select>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
```

Here is CSS Code

```
select {
   -moz-appearance : none;
   text-indent:0.01px;
   text-overflow:'';
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. You want white background color or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement to customize your `dropdown`. So please use `css` for `custom dropdown`. This link will help you...
http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/